# Creating a simple multiple users app in django

Tags: python, django

So I've got three users, a `teacher`, `student`, and `admin`. Both `teacher` and `student` users work fine but when I try to login using the `admin` form, it redirects to the `student` login form. I think it's because there's something wrong with the `urls.py` and the way the `next` parameter is configured but I'm not quite sure where to proceed.

Any help is much appreciated. Let me know if you need more information

Here are my admin views.py

```
@login_required
@admin_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', classroom.home, name='home'),

    path('students/', include(([
        path('', students.QuizListView.as_view(), name='quiz_list'),
        path('interests/', students.StudentInterestsView.as_view(), name='student_interests'),
        path('taken/', students.TakenQuizListView.as_view(), name='taken_quiz_list'),
        path('quiz/<int:pk>/', students.take_quiz, name='take_quiz'),
    ], 'classroom'), namespace='students')),

    path('teachers/', include(([
        path('', teachers.QuizListView.as_view(), name='quiz_change_list'),
        path('quiz/add/', teachers.QuizCreateView.as_view(), name='quiz_add'),
        path('quiz/<int:pk>/', teachers.QuizUpdateView.as_view(), name='quiz_change'),
        path('quiz/<int:pk>/delete/', teachers.QuizDeleteView.as_view(), name='quiz_delete'),
        path('quiz/<int:pk>/results/', teachers.QuizResultsView.as_view(), name='quiz_results'),
        path('quiz/<int:pk>/question/add/', teachers.question_add, name='question_add'),
        path('quiz/<int:quiz_pk>/question/<int:question_pk>/', teachers.question_change, name='question_change'),
        path('quiz/<int:quiz_pk>/question/<int:question_pk>/delete/', teachers.QuestionDeleteView.as_view(), name='question_delete'),
    ], 'classroom'), namespace='teachers')),
    
    path('admins/', include(([
        path('', admins.profile, name='profile'),
    ], 'classroom'), namespace='admins')),
]
```

login urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('classroom.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/signup/', classroom.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('accounts/signup/student/', students.StudentSignUpView.as_view(), name='student_signup'),
    path('accounts/signup/teacher/', teachers.TeacherSignUpView.as_view(), name='teacher_signup'),
    path('accounts/signup/admin/', admins.register, name='register'),
]
```

signup form template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-12">
      <h2>Sign up as a {{ user_type }}</h2>
      <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

admin form template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just removing `@login_required` from your `profile` view.

Since Django decorators work top-down, `@login_required` will kick in *before* `@admin_required`.  But from https://pypi.org/project/django-simple-rest/:

> admin_required simply makes sure that the user is logged in and is
> also a super user before they will be granted access to the decorated
> view method.

So, I think that `@admin_required` will already check if the user is logged in.